# UWP call to WCF service not returning

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp

I have two separate UWP solutions in Visual Studio that connect to a couple of in-house WCF services.

The first solution/project connects to the service and returns data in around 100ms.
The second project tries to get the data and never returns from the service call. With the exact same code. I can't find any difference in the projects. This is the basic client-side code that never gets past line 2, after 10 minutes of waiting.

I created a brand new UWP project that displays the same behaviour, and also a Unit Test project that returns the expected data immediately.

I have turned on WCF trace logging on the server and it seems that the service processes the successful (unit test) requests and the unsuccessful (UWP) requests in exactly the same way.

Can anyone help?

```
        var client = new ChecksServiceReference.ChecksServiceClient();
        ObservableCollection<string> Centres = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        try
        {
            Centres = await client.CentresAsync();
        }
        catch(FaultException ex)
        {
            string x = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            await client.CloseAsync();
        }
        return await Task.FromResult(Centres);
```

Comment: Is your call wrapped in a **try/catch** statement, so that you'll be sure that the request is still pending and didn't crash ?

Comment: yes try/catch is the same - changed code to reflect

Comment: Have you watched the network traffic with something like Fiddler?  Is the request returning?

Comment: I bet that it is sync context deadlock. Try to change that line with call so we can see that it is the problem: 
await client.CentresAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: I had been trying to get the result  from inside of a class constructor by calling the async method synchronously with '.Result' on the end, and this didn't return. Instead I created an async task, within which I called the method using the await keyword. And from within the constructor I called the async task (albeit synchronously, i.e. without await)